# How to view the MBR table and GPT table themselves (not how to check if partition type is MBR or GPT)?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I am trying to understand what exactly are MBR and GPT and so far what I have learned is that they are "tables". So to understand further, I would like to see those tables to see how they look like.

I have already tried every google search term but every result tells you how to check if partition type is MBR or GPT. That is not what I'm asking. What I'm asking is how can I see those tables, as in "table", with rows and columns, just like how you print a routing table or MAC table.

Is there a way view or print the MBR table and GPT table? How to do that in Linux and Windows?

Comment: In Linux, use `sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=first_sector count=1`. Then use a bin/hex editor to view the data in file `first_sector`. The 64 bytes at byte offsets 446 through 509 comprise the MBR table. (The first byte of the sector has offset **0**, and the last is 511.)

Answer (score 2):

The Linux partitioning tools `fdisk` and `gdisk` will show you the contents, mostly. The former is a generic tool, the latter is GPT-only (it can load MBR but will automatically convert to GPT before displaying).

For example, with GPT:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
[some output trimmed]
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E02CF915-B9D0-C445-9A99-3C374F468FBE

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048       6143       4096    2M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     6144    1050623    1044480  510M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1050624 3907028991 3905978368  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

Each line represents a single partition, which is a single partition-table entry. Those are not the *full* columns for GPT, but they're the important ones in any type of partition table – partition **Start** and **End**, as well as the **Type** of the partition. (Ignore 'Device', that's made up by fdisk.)

(Note also that the GPT has a small header before its "table" starts, containing the **Disk identifier** GUID plus a few other parameters. Doing `gdisk -l` would show the other header parameters, such as "holds up to 128 entries", "ends at sector 63", or "first usable sector is 2048".)

For MBR, this would be it – start/end/type is practically all it holds. (Most tools will combine the four 'primary' rows and the variable number of 'logical' rows into one list.) GPT has more fields; entering fdisk's "expert" mode will show a more complete output for GPT:

```
# fdisk /dev/sda
Command: x
Expert command: p

[some output trimmed]
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E02CF915-B9D0-C445-9A99-3C374F468FBE
First usable LBA: 2048
Last usable LBA: 3907029134
Alternative LBA: 3907029167
Partition entries starting LBA: 2
Allocated partition entries: 128
Partition entries ending LBA: 33

Device       Start        End    Sectors Type-UUID                            UUID                                 Name Attrs
/dev/sda1     2048       6143       4096 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649 66361CDC-3217-3D42-B767-C5FAFC905BCF Grub
/dev/sda2     6144    1050623    1044480 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 2977A744-A2C9-6049-AD98-6183B8725B4A Boot
/dev/sda3  1050624 3907028991 3905978368 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 AE341E89-2AA2-DC41-8BD4-BD5FC7527861 Arch
```

This adds the partition's unique GUID (aka "PARTUUID" in Linux, not to be confused with the filesystem's UUID), as well as the raw Type-GUID (which was translated to textual names in the earlier example), the partition's optional name (aka PARTLABEL) and its 64 bits' worth of attribute flags (my system doesn't use any, but a Windows disk would have some). That's about the whole contents of the GPT.

Since all GPT disks also have a "protective" MBR, the `M` expert-mode command can be used to access that:

```
# fdisk /dev/sda
Command: x
Expert command: M
Expert command: p

Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Id Type Start-C/H/S   End-C/H/S Attrs
/dev/sda1           1 3907029167 3907029167 ee GPT        0/0/2 1023/255/63
```

---

Note: I specifically do not recommend 'parted' or GParted, as it has a rather thick abstraction layer – what it calls "flags" often doesn't correspond to actual flags at all; e.g. the `esp` flag in parted actually represents a specific *type* value, and the absence of that flag represents another specific type.

---

At a lower level, the MBR is a data structure *mostly* stored in the 0th sector (LBA) of the disk – the 512-byte LBA contains 440 bytes of boot code and 72 bytes representing the four "primary partition" slots. ("Logical" partition entries are scattered all over the place, however.) Similarly, the GPT is stored in LBAs 1–63 or so, with the header in LBA 1 and the rows starting with LBA 2.

So the ability to read the tables is not limited to just fdisk/gdisk – any tool that can access `/dev/sda` or `\\.\Device\Harddisk1` would work.

For example, many hex editors support opening raw disks, and some of them have built-in support for parsing certain structure. Here's what the "rows" of a GPT look like in HxD, with four partition entries in sector 2 of my SSD (the header in sector 1 is not shown):

[image: Screenshot of HxD, a hex editor, displaying contents of LBA 2 on a GPT-partitioned disk]

HxD is a fairly minimal one that only shows you the raw bytes, but a few more advanced hex editors (e.g. 010 Editor) can apply "templates" that would label the individual fields of common data formats, including MBR and often GPT.

Answer (score 2):

I use DMDE to examine on disk structures like the GPT. You can view in RAW HEX or interpreted using a template. You can view and edit using the free version of DMDE. [www.dmde.com](http://www.dmde.com).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`parted` can give user-viewable information about the partition table
of both MBR and GPT, through its
[print command](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#print).

You may use the `print` command to see header and partitions info.
Using `print free` will also include the free unallocated space.

The output will look like :

```
(parted) print
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2684MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1000MB  999MB   primary                  boot, lba
 2      1000MB  2300MB  1299MB  primary  ext2            lba
 3      2300MB  2500MB  200MB   primary  linux-swap(v1)  lba

(parted) print free
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2684MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
        16.4kB  1049kB  1032kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  1000MB  999MB   primary                  boot, lba
 2      1000MB  2300MB  1299MB  primary  ext2            lba
 3      2300MB  2500MB  200MB   primary  linux-swap(v1)  lba
        2500MB  2684MB  185MB            Free Space
```